# List manipulation logic help needed

Tags: java, algorithm, file, list, logic

H guys,

I'm having a piece of code which would search for some similar .ser files and loads them into a list

the files are (rulesIncr1.ser,rulesIncr2.ser, rulesIncr3.ser ...... and so on)

now to load all the files i have written the following logic

```
String defaultfilename = "rulesincr";
int i=1;
                String incrFile;
                //THE FOLLOWING CODE WILL CHECK FOR ANY NU8MBER OF INCR RULES FILE IN THE LOCATION AND ADD THEM TO A RULE MODEL LIST
                do
                {
                    String tempincr = new Integer(i).toString();
                    incrFile = defaultfilename.concat(tempincr).concat(".ser");
                    FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream( filePath.concat(incrFile));
                    ObjectInputStream inStreamIncr = new ObjectInputStream(fis); 
                    myRulesIncr = (List<RuleModel>)inStreamIncr.readObject();
                    i++;
                }

                while(new File(filePath.concat(incrFile)).isFile());
```

Now the problem I'm facing is each and every time myRulesIncr would be refreshed and only the last file is loaded at the end. I need to have all the loaded files. Please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
myRulesIncr = (List<RuleModel>)inStreamIncr.readObject();
```

in your loop will always override the List to which the `myRulesIncr` variable points. If you want to add all those `RuleModel` instances to `myRulesIncr` you should have something like

```
List<RuleModel> myRulesIncr = new ArrayList<RuleModel>();

while{
//your while loop without the 
//myRulesIncr = (List<RuleModel>)inStreamIncr.readObject(); line
myRules.addAll( (List<RuleModel>)inStreamIncr.readObject() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robin, but eclipse is warning the following Null pointer access: The variable myRulesIncr can only be null at this location

Comment: Then you have not initialized the variable. The message is pretty clear on this

Answer (score 0):

Im unfamiliar with the standard list object but the problem appears to be here:

```
myRulesIncr = (List<RuleModel>)inStreamIncr.readObject();
```

You appear to be making a new list every time, and even if not I believe you need to increment to the next node ie `myRulesIncr = myRulesIncr.next()`